# Changing specific order details text in Woocommerce order received page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gettext, wpml

On the order-recieved page ('`woocommerce_thankyou`') there is a table with the order details a heading **"Order Details"** (`Ordredetaljer` in my native language).

I cannot figure out how to change this heading. I can't even find the source code for it properly. If someone could tell me the string(We use wpml for string translation) or the source code I would be a happy developer.

[image: Picture of the heading in question can be found here]

Comment: The template you are looking for is located in [`order/order-details.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.2/templates/order/order-details.php) (It's used in customer order view too).

Comment: Going by the source it references `Order details` in the `woocommerce` domain. However changing this doesn't reflect in the page. Neither the theme or our child theme has a `woocommerce/order/order-details.php` template that could overwrite this

Comment: You can check if it overrides in backend Woocommerce > status at the end of the page in "Templates"…

Comment: Status shows nothing overriding order-details

Comment: That is very strange… normally it works. Something is wrong somewhere.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec This page is so bloated, i'd be suprised if something was right somewhere

Answer (score 2):

The template you are looking for is located in `order/order-details.php`

But as WooCommerce templates doesn't seem to work in your theme you can try this alternative:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'changes_in_thank_you', 100, 3 );
function changes_in_thank_you( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if( $text === 'Order details' ) {

        $translated_text =  __( 'Your replacement text', $domain );
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

It should work.

To target specifically "Order received" page you can replace:

```
if( $text === 'Order details' ) {
```

by:

```
if( $text === 'Order details' && is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) {
```

---

> **In WPML:**
>
> 1) In **"Theme and plugins localization"** You can load the translatable text for "Woocommerce" plugin scanning this plugin. 
>   2) In **"String translations"** you should be able to find the string **`'Order details'`** for the woocommerce domain and change the yranslation for your language…

Comment: Using this for debugging, i tried to `return "aaaaaaaaaaa"` on all gettext calls. The only thing unaffected was this heading. If nothing overrides this template, and the gettext somehow doesn't supply this translation(it is translated mind you) where i begin debugging this?

Comment: @ChristianPåbølJacobsen I have maid an update at the end… try this.