# How to change or modify woocommerce admin order title by hook?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to add a custom field below the order number or possible to modify the title so, I've tried,

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_before_order_details', 'edit_woocommerce_order_header', 10, 1 ); 

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_number', 'edit_woocommerce_order_header', 10, 1 );
```

but it's doesn't work.

The Only way I can do now is by using jQuery to find the title class like so,

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) 
{ 
   $("Text to replace"). insertAfter( \'.woocommerce-order-data_heading\' );
});
```

For the Woocommerce hook I have no idea.

If anybody have a better approach please share or point me for a guid.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/48267068/8577321

Comment: Thanks @hashemsheikhypour for your help but, my intention to do appending some elements below the order number heading not just replacing matched text!

Comment: you want change number order ? or all heading ?

Comment: @hashemsheikhypour, yes, I prefer to change all heading or append some below!!!